# Repaint() not calling paintComponent() in JComponent class

Tags: java, swing, jcomponent

I'm creating a java app where i use a JComponent class to draw.
I have a problem with the repaint() method not launching paintComponent().
What can be the cause of this?

Code:

JComponent Class:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class Display extends JComponent implements ActionListener{

    private final static int Width = 400;
    private final static int Height = 600;
    private long period;
    private Timer timer;

    private Background background;

    private boolean isRunning = false;

    public Display(long period) {
        this.period = period;
        setSize(Width, Height);
        prepeareUi();
        setOpaque(false);
    }

    public void addNotify() {
        if(!isRunning) {
            timer = new Timer((int)period, this);
            timer.start();
            isRunning = true;
        }
    }

    public void stop() {
        if(isRunning)
            isRunning = false;
    }

    private void prepeareUi() {
        background = new Background(Width, Height);
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, Width, Height);
        background.draw(g);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        if(isRunning) {
            background.update();
            repaint();
            return;
        }

        System.exit(0);

    }

}
```

Frame class:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Frame extends JFrame {

    private static final int DEFAULTFPS = 20;

    public Frame(long period) {
        prepearUI(period);
    }

    private void prepearUI(long period) {
        Display d = new Display(period);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        add(d);
        pack();
        setResizable(false);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[]args) {
        String fpsS = null;
        if(args.length==1)
            fpsS = args[0];

        int fps = (fpsS != null) ? Integer.parseInt(fpsS) :  DEFAULTFPS;
        long period = (long) (1000.0/fps); //In Ms!

        Frame f = new Frame(period);
    }

}
```

Background class

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;


public class Background {

    private int ParentWidth;
    private int ParentHeight;

    private int width;
    private int height;

    private BufferedImage image;

    private float x = 0;
    private float y = 0;

    private final static float ANIMATIONSPEED = 1F;
    private final static int ANIMATION_RIGHT = 0;
    private final static int ANIMATION_LEFT = 1;

    private int animationway = 1;

    public Background(int W, int H) {
        ParentWidth = W;
        ParentHeight = H;
        prepeareImage();
    }

    private void prepeareImage() {
        width = 0; height = 0;
        try {
            image = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("UI\\background.png"));
            width = image.getWidth(null);
            height = image.getHeight(null);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Background.png not found!");
        }
    }

    public void update() {
        if(animationway == ANIMATION_RIGHT) {
            x += ANIMATIONSPEED;
            if(x>=0F) {
                animationway = ANIMATION_LEFT;
            }
        }

        if(animationway == ANIMATION_LEFT) {
            x -= ANIMATIONSPEED;
            if(x<=width/-1+ParentWidth) {
                animationway = ANIMATION_RIGHT;
            }
        }
    }

    public void draw(Graphics g) {
        g.drawImage(image, (int) x, (int) y, null);
    }

}
```

Comment: Use getPreferredSize over setSize; call super.paintComponent before performing custom painting

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that your override of `addNotify` did not call the parent's implementation. This broke many things, proper repaint notifications is probably one of them. You can fix this by adding `super.addNotify();` to your implementation.

But I would not touch `addNotify` at all. Don't override it. Initialize the timer in a constructor or add a method that a parent can call to start the timer. You already have method `stop()` so just create method `start()`.

[JComponent.addNotify()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#addNotify%28%29) documentation states:

> Notifies this component that it now has a parent component. When this
>   method is invoked, the chain of parent components is set up with
>   KeyboardAction event listeners. This method is called by the toolkit
>   internally and should not be called directly by programs.

*EDIT:*

To avoid breaking the paint chain make sure you call `super.paintComponent()` in your implementation of `paintComponent()`. For more details see [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) and [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html).

Comment: Can you add a comment about breaking the paint chain by not calling super.paintComponent